# Understanding the conformal invariance of the scalar massless wave equation

Tags: field-theory, conformal-field-theory

It can be shown mathematically that the scalar massless wave equation is conformally invariant. However, doing so is rather tedious and muted in terms of physical understanding. As such, is there a physically intuitive explanation as to why the scalar massless wave equation is conformally invariant?

Comment: you might find this mathoverflow thread interesting : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/270088/why-is-conformal-invariance-only-possible-for-massless-theories , but the general mantra is that if you have masses in your theory, they define length scales, so you shouldn't expect conformal invariance (and conversely, you have some reason to believe there is conformal invariance when there are no length scales around). E.g. this is more or less what happens when you drive condensed matter systems to criticality - their characteristic length scales get driven to infinity

Answer (score 0):

conformal invariance means we have the all of the following:

1. rotational invariance
2. scale invariance
3. special conformal invariance
4. translation invariance

now since wave equation does not have any potential term it  fullfills 4. since it is scalar and again does not have any external field being applied it full fills 1. now since it is massless it  fullfills 2. mass $m$ has a dimension same as momentum it is one over length. thus because of that under scale transformation, the terms with $m$ in equation of motion changes. Since in your case there is no mass term it full fills 2. 3. is not very important 1 2 4 are important and this the intiuitive explanation.